# Spring Boot native:compile with multi module Maven build

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, graalvm-native-image

I try to compile GraalVM Native Image for a Spring Boot 3.0 application with multiple Maven modules.

The module structure is like the following:

```
heroes-parent
|- heroes-backend
|- heroes-frontend
|- heroes-webapp
```

where each sub-directory is a module of the parent

pom.xml extract:

```xml
  <modules>
    <module>heroes-backend</module>
    <module>heroes-frontend</module>
    <module>heroes-webapp</module>
  </modules>
```

When I try to build the app with (see [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.developing-your-first-application.native-build-tools.maven)):

```
mvn -Pnative native:compile
```

it errors with (because the parent has no classes):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.18:compile (default-cli) on project heroes-parent: Image classpath is empty. Check if your classpath configuration is correct. -> [Help 1]
```

So, I have tried to build the whole application first with `mvn install` and then only build the application `heroes-webapp` with `native:compile`

```
mvn install 
cd heroes-webapp
mvn -Pnative native:compile
```

But this fails with the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.047 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-12T16:26:20+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.0:process-aot (process-aot) on project heroes-webapp: Unable to compile generated source
[ERROR] cannot access heroes.WeblateProperties
[ERROR]   bad class file: /home/koc/git/work/koc/angular-spring-heroes/heroes-webapp/target/classes/heroes/WeblateProperties.class
[ERROR]     unable to access file: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/koc/git/work/koc/angular-spring-heroes/heroes-webapp/target/classes/heroes/WeblateProperties.class
[ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath. /home/koc/git/work/koc/angular-spring-heroes/heroes-webapp/target/spring-aot/main/sources/heroes/WeblateProperties__BeanDefinitions.java 15:25
[ERROR] cannot access heroes.MainController
[ERROR]   bad class file: /home/koc/git/work/koc/angular-spring-heroes/heroes-webapp/target/classes/heroes/MainController.class
[ERROR]     unable to access file: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/koc/git/work/koc/angular-spring-heroes/heroes-webapp/target/classes/heroes/MainController.class
[ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath. /home/koc/git/work/koc/angular-spring-heroes/heroes-webapp/target/spring-aot/main/sources/heroes/MainController__BeanDefinitions.java 15:25
[ERROR] cannot access heroes.HeroesApplication
[ERROR]   bad class file: /home/koc/git/work/koc/angular-spring-heroes/heroes-webapp/target/classes/heroes/HeroesApplication.class
[ERROR]     unable to access file: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/koc/git/work/koc/angular-spring-heroes/heroes-webapp/target/classes/heroes/HeroesApplication.class
[ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath. /home/koc/git/work/koc/angular-spring-heroes/heroes-webapp/target/spring-aot/main/sources/heroes/HeroesApplication__BeanDefinitions.java 18:25
```

You can find the [source code for the whole application on GitHub](https://github.com/porscheinformatik/angular-spring-heroes).

Is there any way to build a native-image with a Maven multi-module Spring Boot 3 application?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Visual Studio Code was open and the project was loaded using [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack). This was deleting the classes while Maven was building them which resulted in the error above.